# Liferay database access level (Site Level)?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme

I have a requirement that I need to restrict the liferay database in site level.

Let me first explain my scenario.

- Admin is the one who will create the site and site admins.
- Here admin user is the owner and sites are different clients.
- Now each site will treat as a different client.
- So the site admin have privileges to see only his site related data
  in the data base but not others site data.

How can I handle this situation?

- Do I need to use the multiple databases for multiple clients/sites?
- How do I maintain the different database for different client? Any
  suggestion please?

**Note:** I am not using Organizations, we are using only sites.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you need. Based on my understanding, you can create separate `instance` for each client in liferay and use database sharding. `Database sharding` will allows you to have different db for each client.

HTH.

Comment: If we create a separate instance, Then does that instance has an admin user? I need that the new instance will be managed by site admin with site admin privileges and not with admin privileges.

Comment: Every Instance will have own admin user. I would suggest you to read about liferay roles and instance in liferay

Comment: Yes, sure I will do that. max how many databases will Databse sharding supports?

Comment: You can check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupID to split the users to some groups: Group Admin and Group Normal User.
Not to use different database for diffirent client. Because 2 group have some same points.You need only one database for all of things you want to do.But you can customize it follow GroupID ^^
Good luck!

Comment: But every client will request for different database to view their own data.

Comment: I am taking about database view not on UI. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You use GroupID in each datatable able to view or not to view with role of users. When you add data content , save the GroupID of people logan and fill that ID to datatable with data content

Comment: The nature of database's divide follow groupID too. You can devide only one database to some part belong to one groupID